# Java subtleties in the foreach loop

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator

If I have a 2d array of objects, and want to initialize them all, I call a loop, eg:

```
for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<len; j++)
        objects[i][j] = new MyObject();
```

Which works fine, but when I tried doing this with the for-each construct, it didn't work and the entire array remains null:

```
for(MyObject[] intermediate: objects)
    for(MyObject obj: intermediate)
        obj = new MyObject();
```

How come they behave differently?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2556419/1140748

Comment: @alain.janinm: Don't close, because the other question only handles simple Arrays, not nested Arrays. You can initialise the outer Array that way - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assigment

```
obj = new MyObject();
```

just set a new object in the variable `obj`, and does not change the value in the array, it only changes the reference variable `obj`.

What happens is that  `objects[i][j]` is assined to `obj`, and then you change the value of `obj`, without changing the actual array.

when you assign directly to `objects[i][j]` - it works as expected, since you change the value of `objects[i][j]`, which is exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

References are passed by value, so `obj = new MyObject();` only updates the local copy of your reference to `objects[i][j]`.

Answer (score 1):

It only works for the outer loop, because there are new references being made, but not deep ones:

```
public static void main (String[] args ) {
    Integer [][] iaa = new Integer[3][4];
    for (Integer[] ia : iaa) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; ++i) {
            ia[i] = i; 
        }
    }
}
```