# Is it possible to initialise an array in the for each loop's condition area?

Tags: java, foreach

In python, you can do this:

```
for item in [a, b, c, d]:
    some-code
```

Is something similar possible in java, where you declare the array in the for loop condition area?

My gut reaction is to do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String string : String myArr[] = {a, b, c, d}) {
        some-code
    }
}
```

But that does not work

Note: I did a preliminary search before asking, the similar-seeming question I found ([Initializing an array in Java using the 'advanced' for each loop [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556419/initializing-an-array-in-java-using-the-advanced-for-each-loop)) is different.

Comment: `for (String string : new String[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}) {...}`?

Comment: See also: [How to initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java) and [How do I declare and initialize an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you learn something new everyday. Apparently you can initialize an array but you must define the type and not just use an array initializer.

**This works**

```java
        for (String string : new String[] { "a", "b", "c" }) {
            //code
        }
```

**This doesn't work** because it's unaware of type.

```java
        for (String string : { "a", "b", "c" }) {
            //code
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, is it possible to create an array of other arrays like this?
Let's say you have the other arrays' data ready, then is it possible to define the 2D array with syntax like this?

Comment: "This doesn't work because it's unaware of type." No, this doesn't work because the array initializer syntax only works in the initializer of a variable declaration.

Comment: (As in: `String[] arr; arr = {};` doesn't work either, despite there being as much information about what type of array to create as `String[] arr = {}`).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly initialize array with the help of `Arrays.asList()` method call in java.
A sample code snippet is shown as follows:

```
for(String data: Arrays.asList("a","b","c"){
    // code here
}
```