# for each loop cannot initialize objects in array

Tags: java, syntax, for-loop

I will dive quick to the problem. I have a straightforward class

```
class Vector{
    float x, y;
}
```

and another class has an array of these objects as its member

```
Vector[] buffer;
```

I initialize it like this:

```
buffer = new Vector[8];
for(Vector v: buffer)
    v = new Vector();
```

but when I try to access this objects' members in this array I get a NullPointerException straight to my stack trace. That is, objects of array have not been constructed. On the other hand this more traditional code works just perfect:

```
buffer = new Vector[8];
for(int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    buffer[i] = new Vector;
```

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) discussion points it out, both should be the same after compilation.

My question is, why for each loop fails to initialize/construct objects from the item array?

Comment: If you use buffer.length in your for loop instead of repeating 8 then it will always be correct to the size of your array. Otherwise if you change one 8 and not the other then you will miss the end elements or get an array out of bound exception.

Comment: It was just for the sake of example. Actually assigning buffer.length to a variable before for loop and using it for condition is a bit better for performance -almost negligible- and is my convention.

Comment: Well there is even a question about exactly that optimization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208320/what-is-the-cost-of-calling-array-length

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your for-each example you are overwriting the local variable of the loop which does not get saved back into the array. It is similar to in your second loop going:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++){
    Vector v = buffer[i];
    v = new Vector();
}
```

Check out [Understanding for each loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589433/understanding-for-each-loop-in-java) for basically the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Both loops are the same for *accessing* elements from an array, but not for initializing them. When you use a for-each loop in this scenario, it's like doing

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    Vector v = array[x];
    v = new Vector();
}
```

You are not assigning the new `Vector` to the array, instead you are assigning it to a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, `v` is available only inside the for loop. When you do `v = new Vector();` v is updated, but not buffer[i]. v was pointing to buffer[i] before, now it points to a new vector, `buffer[i]` remains as `null`.